# Integrating $\int{\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(x+\sqrt{1-x^2})^2} dx}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, fractions

I am a little bit lost with integral: $$\int{\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(x+\sqrt{1-x^2})^2} dx}$$

I have already worked on in and done substitution $x = \sin(t)$:

This brings me to: $$\int{\frac{\cos(t)^2}{(\sin(t)+\cos(t))^2}dt}$$

Further treating denominator to achieve:

$$\int{\frac{\cos(t)^2}{\sin(2t)+1}dt}$$

I can split this fraction into two integrals by doing $\cos(t)^2 = 1-\sin(t)^2$ but this doesn't help me to solve the integral further.

Please, can you show me how to continue to "break it" :-)

Best thanks!

Comment: I know you have a solution now, I added this part if you don't accept it please delete it

Comment: In ADDED there is a typo at the beginning since $\displaystyle{\cos^2(t) = {1 \color{#f00}{\LARGE+} \cos(2t) \over 2}}$

Comment: @Semsem Please do not add your answers to the OP... submit it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do a follow up to OP's substitution. We need to find
$$\int \frac{\cos^2 t}{(\sin t+\cos t)^2}\,dt.$$

Note that $\sin t+\cos t=\sqrt{2}\cos(t-\pi/4)$. If we let $u=t-\pi/4$, then $\cos t=\cos(u+\pi/4)$. Expand. We get $\cos t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\cos u-\sin u)$. Square. The rest is straightforward.

Comment: Actually this is what I am looking for. Thank's for the kind advice. Regards!

Comment: You are welcome. Complicating the numerator slightly is fine, as long as the denominator becomes nice. We could also have let $x+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ be $u$.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a trig substitution, expand the denominator and simplify the integrand.

Comment: Thanks. I have done it, but i am not able to simplify it any better. Getting the same as with the substitution.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken- on mobile and did it in my head.